# Integrate third-party payment providers into Hybris

Tags: payment-gateway, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to integrate a third-party payment provider into Hybris. It does not have any extension for hybris yet like PayPal, etc. I read the document about payment and payment adapter extention from Hybris Wiki but it does not provide much information about actual steps for implementation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The integration depends on your PSP and the contract you passed. There is no out of the box implementation. What hybris propose is an interface with common method names. You can then use this interface and bind behind the PSP you want. But you'll have to code the link between hybris payment interface and the chosen PSP.

Comment: I'm doing such a link up code first time. Could you provide some sample code or references how this link between hybris payment interface and PSP can be done, if possible?

Comment: It's not mandatory to use the payment interface from hybris. You can also just call WS from your PSP in your custom code. The advantage of using the payment extension is to have a code not specific to a provider. The lin of the documentation : https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8c25f07586691014bc1fecf207503685.html

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a good idea to understand hybris payment extension and how Cybersource  extension (provided with hybris) works. This will help to implement your PSP properly.

The implementation depends also on your order lifeCycle and what they are payment interactions with the PSP : Auth, Capture, Refund, Partial capture...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try *Adyen* or *Ogone* payment extensions, they come as addons to Hybris and can be set up pretty easily, more details on these addons can be found [here](https://www.hybris.com/en/products/extensions/adyen)